# Cannot connect Hc-05 with PIC16f877A

Tags: pic, bluetooth, microchip, pic16f

I am trying to connect my HC-05 bluetooth module with PIC16F877A. I know we have to use USART to talk with bluetooth module. So I started with USART of PIC by reading its datasheet.

I am using MPLABX IDE with XC8 compiler and i am not interested in using any libraries.

```
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS       // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)



// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#include<xc.h>

void main(void)
{

unsigned int i;
TRISA=0xff;

//UART
TRISC=0X00;
TXSTA=0X20; // TX RS232 settings
RCSTA=0X80; // RX RS232 Settings
SPBRG=31; // Baud rate is set based on Crystal clock

TXSTAbits.TXEN=1; // Enable RS232 transmission
RCSTAbits.SPEN=1; // Enable RS232 reception

while(1)
{

TXREG= 65;
__delay_ms(200); 

}
}
```

I used the above code to send a char 'A' from PIC to USART and was successful in reading it using my serial monitor on PC (with RS232).

Now form what I understood, if I replace the RS232 with my bluetooth module I should get the same char 'A' transmitted to my mobile phone.

I am using Bluetooth Terminal android app to check the reception of data. But the after the app connects to the module it just shows a blank screen. I dont receive anything.

What could be the reason please help me!!!!!!.

**Things that I tried :**

1. There is no problem with the baud-rate, both my Rs232 and HC-05 works at 9600. I have ensured the same using my arduino and HC-05.
2. there is no logic level problem I have used a potential divider to shift 5V to 3.3V.

I am quite new here so forgive me if my question is not that appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Hi guys I finally made a full working program for interfacing PIC with HC-05. The complete details can be found here: https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/bluetooth-interfacing-with-pic-microcontroller

Comment: It's better to include code into your answer instead of referring to some external page. And include explanation what fixed your problem.

Comment: Why is that? Why should I create a duplicate when I have already posted the details there?  NO OFFENCE!! Just curious to know.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Good answer = you explain solution to the problem in this answer. Bad answer = link to another site where is the answer.